# How can I reverse every line in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, notepad++, reverse

Is it possible to reverse all of lines in Notepad++?

Example:

```
Hello:world
Best:Friend
The most:beautiful flower
```

Would change to

```
world:Hello
Friend:Best
beautiful flower:The most
```

Answer (score 3):

Find `(.*):(.*)` and replace with `$2:$1`. This finds 2 capturing groups separated by colon and replaces with them reversed.

Comment: Actually, with the line breaks hidden in the questions source, this might work. Tried this with Geany, using `\2:\1` instead, and it worked fine.